# Moving Innodb database from Server A to server b

Tags: mysql

Instead of using dump, is there a way I can move the data files from one server to another instead?

We are migrating our application to a new server in January, the one concern is the downtime when taking the first server offline to do a dump of the database and the time to restore it on a new server.

I'm finding dump and restore are taking a long time due to the size of the database.

UPDATE:
Operating system is windows server
Old server is 5.5
New server is 8.0

Comment: How long is it currently taking? How big is the database? How fast do you need it to run?

Comment: We're missing some key information, like what version are you running on the old server and in the new server? How big is the database?

Comment: @AnthonyGenovese - the retore is failing, row length is too much.  over 100GB.  As quick as possible

Comment: @jerichorivera old server is 5.5, new is 8.0 but I can uninstall and match versions if required.

Comment: take note of [upgrading directly from MySQL 5.6 to 8.0 is not supported.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/upgrade-paths.html)

Answer (score 0):

Tables can be moved in physical form, although it is not instant: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-table-import.html

A more automated way would to use partial or full backups with tools such as mysql enterprise backup or Percona XtraBackup: https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup which will allow you to backup a database quickly without impacting sourde database availability.

In the future, having a replica of your database will be the easiest way to increase your availability during maintenance (switchovers should only take seconds).

Comment: unfortunately percona isn't for windows.  Looking at the other link, I'm not sure with the limitations if this is a valid option.  I did push for replication but budget wouldn't allow for it at the time.  I was hoping I could just copy the data files for the database and move those only.

Comment: You can copy the files, but you will need to stop the mysql service.

Comment: Any instructions on how to do that?

Comment: stop mysql, copy all files on datadir, as well as the configuration file using the method you prefer (e.g. scp, sftp), start mysql again on the original server, start mysql on the new server with the copy config (you may want to have a look at certain things like memory usage, paths, etc.), delete databases you are not happy with on the new server. BTW, if you wanted to setup a real-time replica, you could do it easily at the same time, with a few extra steps, even of a partial copy.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of how you end up doing the migration, test it first.  5.5->8.0 is 3 *major* upgrades.

The dump+reload may fail due to some important change between the levels.  A binary dump will definitely fail.

What is your DR (Disaster Recovery) plan?  That is, what would happen if there were an extended power failure?  Or a non-recoverable disk failure?

Maybe now is the time to worry both about DR *and* upgrading.

Step 1 *might* be to build a 5.5 Slave by doing `mysqldump ... | mysql ...` to copy the data to another Windows machine with 5.5.  At the same time, set up replication.  Yes, this will take time.

Step 2 would be to upgrade (in place) the Slave to 5.6 and test it.  Then to 5.7 and test.  Then to 8.0 and test.  Be sure to use mysql_upgrade at each step.

Step 3 test

Step 4 Build an 8.0 slave off the 8.0 slave.  (Now you have 5.5->8.0->8.0)

Step 5 test

Step 6 would be to "failover", promoting the middle Slave to Master.  Test.  And point the clients to it.

Step 7 Jettison the 5.5 box; it is now useless.

Notes:
Step 1 is the slowest and has most downtime.
Step 6 has a small downtime.
With some more work (somewhere around Step 4), you could switch over to Unix.  This would let you do LVM snapshots and/or Xtrabackup to make future actions much faster.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using dbForge with a trail period  and it copied the database without issue.  It still took many hours.  The upgrade form 5.5 to 8 was fine but my database is tables only and nothing odd with the data structure.

Thank you all for you advise and help.